# Should services detail be put in hasOfferCatalog within LocalBusiness schema or on service pages via Service schema?

Tags: google-search, schema.org, local-seo

Should services detail be put in `hasOfferCatalog` within `LocalBusiness` schema in home page, or should it be put on service pages via `Service` schema?